# Synchronizing two hosted git repositorities

Tags: git, cron

I have a project using submodule that I need to keep in sync between two servers, each with a full set of repositories. The simplest solution, of course, is to have each developer add both remotes to each repo, and always push to both. But inevitably that's error-prone, and they forget to delete branches, and who knows what other mistakes are made.

The branches don't need to be kept in sync immediately, so I was thinking of using some type of cron job to fetch from one and push to the other (all development is done is one; the second is currently being used almost like a backup).

I thought about using something like:

```
for b in `git branch -r | grep <get only one remote's branches>`
do
    git update-ref refs/heads/$b origin/$b
done
git push --all origin2
```

within a `git submodule foreach`, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it.

I also didn't find an easy way to make sure that deleted branches in `origin` are also deleted in `origin2` (for this purpose, any branch that is not present in `origin` can be assumed to be have been deleted).

It's also complicated slightly by the case of what happens if/when someone adds a new submodule to a branch of the superproject, but those cases are rare enough that I can handle them manually, I suppose.

I admit I don't fully understand the difference in a bare repository and a clone; I suspect a bare repo can help me somehow here, but if I clone the superproject as a bare repo, I don't see how to get the submodules themselves (though perhaps that's related to the paragraph above; without being on a branch, there's no meaning to the submodules).

Might it be wiser to just mirror each repo individually without trying to do so using submodule foreach?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> I also didn't find an easy way to make sure that deleted branches in origin are also deleted in origin2

That is what `fetch.prune` is for:

```
git config fetch.prune true
```

Which leads me to another approach: `git pull` instead of `git push` (that way, you sidestep the bare repo issue, which is preferred when using a `git push`)

Comment: That will delete a local branch when the remote is deleted, but it won't push the deletion to the remote. How can I tell it, during push, "make the remote look exactly like the local" and not just "update the remote branches that match the local branches".

Comment: Also, I didn't understand your comment about pull instead of push. I can't run anything on the second server (or did you mean something else?)

Comment: @Mikeage I meant `git pull` from locally. Combined with the `fetch.prune`, a branch deletion locally will end up deleted on the remote when the other developer (on the second server) does his or her own `git pull`. In short, pull, don't push.

Comment: gotcha. Unfortunately, there is no remote user on the second server. The two repositories are a hosted gitorious, and a regular server running only SSH and gitweb for the UI. We're currently using the hosted gitorious, but for corporate reasons, need to keep our code on the "official" server. Eventually we will, but for now, I just want to mirror my code there (for the CI system, etc).